# Perl's thaw() implementation in Java

Tags: java, perl, freeze-thaw

I have two applications running concurrently: one in Perl, and one in Java. The Perl app relies on using nfreeze to store objects in the database. If my Java app has access to that database, how can I "thaw" that object inside of the Java application?

I don't need to be able to write to that object, just read it and use it in the Java app.

Comment: The answer is: you don't. Use a language agnostic serialization method; JSON, for example.

Comment: You might be able to get it to work with [jerl](https://code.google.com/p/jerl/), but I would use JSON or protocol buffers myself.

Answer (score 5):

Storable is specifically designed for Perl data structures. It hasn't been ported to other languages.

Instead of (or in addition to) using Storable, use XML, JSON or YAML (in no particular order).

It's that's not possible, your Java program is going to have to call a Perl script to translate the data into something more convenient.